# By using the Fixed-Point Iteration, I have to find the roots of $f(x)=x^2-x-1=0$

Tags: calculus, roots

By using the Fixed-Point Iteration, I have to find the roots of $f(x)=x^2-x-1=0$

First I write it in terms $x=f(x)$
$$x^2=x+1$$
$$x=1+\frac{1}{x}$$

Then I make a sequence $x_{n+1}=1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_n}$

Now I pick $x_1=2$
$$x_{2}=1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_1}=1.5$$
$$x_{3}=1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_2}=1.6666$$
$$x_{4}=1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_3}=1.6$$
$$x_{5}=1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_4}=1.625$$
$$x_{6}=1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{x_5}=1.612538462$$

So it is converging to $1.618$ which is the root, but how do I find the other root?

Comment: Once you have found one root, say $\alpha$, then the other root is $1 - \alpha$ by Vieta's formula.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
x=1+\frac1x\\
x-1=\frac1x\\
\frac{1}{x-1} =x
$$
Now use that one and start with $x_1=-1$

Answer (score 1):

The product of both roots is $-1{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Using this and the convergence of the sequence you gave, you get that
$$
y_n = -\frac 1{x_n} = -\frac 1{1 + \frac 1{x_{n-1}}} 
= -\frac 1{1 -y_{n-1}} = \frac 1{y_{n-1} - 1}
$$
converges, giving Arthur's answer.

---

Or, following Ben's suggestion,

$$
y_n = 1 - x_n = 1-\left[1 + \frac 1{x_{n-1}}\right] = 
-\frac 1{x_{n-1}} = -\frac 1{1-y_{n-1}} = \frac 1{y_{n-1}-1} 
$$

converges also to the root desired.

Comment: You probably mean the sum of the roots, the product of the roots is $-1$

Comment: @Ben thanks.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: (+1), but I think it is easier to use the sum of roots

Comment: @Ben I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The test will converge to the closest root to $x_n$. Because you chose 2 for $x_n$, it converged to $1.618$. But if you chose something closer to the other root, you will see it converges to $-0.618$.